# Form submit through ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I this form:

```
<form method="post" id="userForm" name="userForm" class="form-validate" action="/istuff/index.php/user" >
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="user"/>
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="user"/>
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="saveUser"/>
<input type="hidden" name="layout" value="edit_address"/>
<input type="hidden" name="address_type" value="ST"/>
<button class="button" type="submit"
</form>
```

And I have ajax script for this form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#userForm").live("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"), // Get the action URL to send AJAX to
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(), // get all form variables
        success: function(result){
            // ... do your AJAX post result
        }
    });
    }); 
});
```

Form works well without AJAX, but then I add this script it doesn't work. Moreover, I tried to go to the link to which is used in AJAX call (copy location with parameters (full link with parameters submitted) - it redirects me to totally different page than, then I submit form wihout ajax.

Comment: you are missing the  dataType: "???" and  contentType: "application/???" in your ajax call

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this is :

1) Remove the 'action' attribute in your 'form' declaration and change the button to a regular button (not a submit)

2) In the jQuery ajax call, directly provide the url.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/istuff/index.php/user",
```

It is also recommended practice to disable the button when the form is submitted and enable it back once the ajax response comes back, to prevent the user clicking the button again. You may also give further visual indication that the request is being processed. I like to use the blockUI jquery plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope This will do the trick:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#userForm").submit(function () {
    var form = $("$userForm");
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"), // Get the action URL to send AJAX to
        type: "POST",
        data: form,
        success: function(result){
            // ... do your AJAX post result
        }
    });
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

I tried your code by changing the following line and it worked,

```
$("#userForm").on("submit", function (event) {
```